# qnx libimg how to encode png to memory

Tags: image, qnx

In my case, I want to encode a pixel buffer into a piece of memory in png format.I just write the code:

```
            BYTE* pbtBuffer     = new BYTE[img.w * img.h];
            s_writeBufferSize           = img.w * img.h;

            io_stream_t* pOutStream = io_open( IO_MEM, IO_WRITE, img.w * img.h, pbtBuffer );
            if ( !pOutStream )
            {
                CLogApp::info( String::format( L"io_open error: %d", errno ) );
                return FALSE;
            }

            pOutStream->output.write_f = ioMemoryWrite;
```

But I cannot  do io_open( IO_MEM...) with IO_WRITE.  I search the qnx forum and find that qnx not support the IO_WRITE with IO_MEM.

How can I do this. Can someone help me? Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!